# Matplotlib Basemap Equivalent Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib

Non Code general question:  I am running Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda distribution) and new to Python.  I want to create a heat map over layed onto map of USA.  All searches I've done say use 'basemap' which seems to be unsupported in Python 3.  What alternatives are out there (do not want to revert to previous Python).

Comment: The [basemap site](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html) says under *requirements*: `Python 2.4 (or later, including Python 3)`. I also haven't heard anyone saying that it doesn't run under python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Seaborn](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/seaborn/) python module it works for `python3` as well.

And [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) is the help regarding heatmap using seaborn.

---

Or you may use [Geoplot](https://github.com/andrea-cuttone/geoplotlib) python module

[image: Plotting using Geoplot.]

Answer (score 0):

[`geoplot`](https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot) is another library that allows you to create [choropleth maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map). These can then be overlayed on a webmap using [`mplleaflet`](https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet).

Answer (score 0):

Basemap is supported in python 3.  With the anaconda install of python 3.7 I used `conda install basemap`. At this point you might need to set you `PROJ_LIB` if you are running in the base environment, as shown in the following example script:

```
import os
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Anaconda3\pkgs\proj4-5.2.0-ha925a31_1\Library\share'
```

Now you should be able to use basemap in python 3.  Here's an example I adapted from Dan Nguyen's [github](https://gist.github.com/dannguyen/eb1c4e70565d8cb82d63) (I removed the Earthquake data and just left the map itself, see the link for neat stuff):

```
# %matplotlib  # in iPython
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
earth = Basemap()
earth.bluemarble(alpha=0.42)
earth.drawcoastlines(color='#555566', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

Resultant image:
[image: worldbasemap from python3.7]